# what is the encoded format of airbus kaggle?

Tags: image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

I'm try to understand the format of the segmentation. 
The format of segmentation of air bus detection of kaggle

```
264661 17 265429 33 266197 33 266965 33 267733...
```

looks something like this. it does not look like voc format 
what kind of format is this?

Comment: What is the competition link? And what is the filename of the data?
Try to put more example lines.

Comment: its called air bus ship detection kaggle

Answer (score 0):

The evaluation page explains the format. 
https://www.kaggle.com/c/airbus-ship-detection/overview/evaluation

```
In order to reduce the submission file size, our metric uses run-length encoding on the pixel values. Instead of submitting an exhaustive list of indices for your segmentation, you will submit pairs of values that contain a start position and a run length. E.g. '1 3' implies starting at pixel 1 and running a total of 3 pixels (1,2,3).

The competition format requires a space delimited list of pairs. For example, '1 3 10 5' implies pixels 1,2,3,10,11,12,13,14 are to be included in the mask. The pixels are one-indexed
and numbered from top to bottom, then left to right: 1 is pixel (1,1), 2 is pixel (2,1), etc. A prediction of of "no ship in image" should have a blank value in the EncodedPixels column.

The metric checks that the pairs are sorted, positive, and the decoded pixel values are not duplicated. It also checks that no two predicted masks for the same image are overlapping.
```